# missing FROM-clause entry for table "u"

Tags: postgresql

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT
    u.id as "u.id",
    u.duration as "u.duration",
    u.email_address as "u.email_address",
    u.phone_number as "u.phone_number",
    u.created_at as "u.created_at",
    u.document as "u.document"
FROM
    new_items
```

and I am getting this error :

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "u"

Comment: `from new_items` --> `from new_items u`

Answer (score 1):

you are referring your table with alias "u" when you are selecting columns like u.id but you have not given that alias to your table , either remove aliases from column list ( u.) or give the alias to your table name :

```
SELECT
    u.id as "u.id",
    u.duration as "u.duration",
    u.email_address as "u.email_address",
    u.phone_number as "u.phone_number",
    u.created_at as "u.created_at",
    u.document as "u.document"
FROM
    new_items as u --< here
```

using `as` keyword is optional

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
    u.id as "id",
    u.duration as "duration",
    u.email_address as "email_address",
    u.phone_number as "phone_number",
    u.created_at as "created_at",
    u.document as "document"

 FROM
    new_itemse as u
```